# Why was I just awarded a bunch of "Announcer" badges?

Tags: support, badges, notifications, global-inbox

My "new achievements" grail recently alerted me that I received 36 Announcer badges **today**. I'm pretty sure I didn't just have 25 people hit all of these shared links, and I'm not even sure these are links that I've shared.

Below is a screenshot of my inbox. Note the scroll bar depth and the number of sites. These are all from today — recently, I believe.

[image: Scores of announcer badges from today on different sites.]

Is this a bug? If so, it's probably not limited to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok, so it wasn't just me and I am losing my mind for completely unrelated reasons. That is definitely good, I honestly thought I broke something lmao

Comment: Gold "publicist" badge. I'll take it.

Comment: We all have an "Amazing Grace" hat now ;)

Comment: I thought I became famous overnight :D

Comment: Now I feel sad because I didn't get a single badge.

Comment: I was pretty sure, I had a few more badges for a while, but they are gone.  That bug reverse worked for me... no kidding.

Comment: Isn't it possible to game this by sharing lots of links to posts, hoping that some will get later visits from other people?  I got the Booster and Announcer badges and all I'd done is paste some shared links into my diary. I didn't share with anyone else.

Comment: Bronze announcer badge: announce new features to the community. Silver announcer badge: announce new features to the community _before_ they go live on the site. Gold announcer badge: announce new features to the community before they go live and wait for feedback before implementing them.

Comment: Good heavens, @CodyGray -- that's, um, a substantial edit. :thinking-face:

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS "*sharing lots of links to posts*" - precisely that **is** the game.

Comment: Oh wow. After reading this meta post I took a look at [my badge list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer?userid=1048572), and it seems I got around 70 badges yesterday and additional 25 today. Looks like I shared a lot links to answers… And [jfs did even better](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260?page=7&userid=4279). He got around 400 badges through this change - congrats!

Comment: I got an announcer badge for a post that was deleted years ago....

Comment: @ruffin Yes. I chose to feature your question on every logged-in users’ sidebar, and the edits were a first step to that. I removed information that was not relevant, reduced the size of the image to make it easier to scroll to what visitors care about (the answer), and a variety of other things. Edits like this are common on Meta, and *especially* for Q&A that gets turned into a [[meta-tag:faq]] or [[meta-tag:featured]]. You’re not going to like that I’m going to edit again. At the very least, featured posts should not demonstrate anti-patterns, like “Edit:”…

Comment: @Bergi [VonC got around 1,5K](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260?page=16&userid=6309)!

Answer (score 332, accepted):

There was a bug in the original logic for awarding "Announcer" badges, which was fixed today.

I've explained it on the global Meta site, but I'll copy [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340289) here:

> Thanks for reporting this. The query was broken and has been for a
>   little while. It should now be fixed along with some improvements to
>   it.
>
> The original queries the sharing badges,
>   [Announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer),
>   [Booster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/booster) and
>   [Publicist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/publicist),
>   were supposed to count the total number of unique IP Addresses that
>   visited from a link shared to a question.
>
> In order to calculate this we would use the `PostId` from the link
>   shared and join back to the `Posts` table to aggregate the total
>   visits under each question. This process worked great for questions
>   shared, but as you found out there was an issue when answers were
>   shared. There was a bug that was introduced into the code during an
>   earlier optimization that wasn't properly looking for the `ParentId`
>   when an answer was shared. As a result, answers were not being
>   included in the awarding of badges.
>
> After a lot of testing this week, we determined that the easiest and
>   most efficient way to fix this is to award these badges based on the
>   `PostId` that is shared instead of basing it on the question.
>
> This means that if you share a link to a question, an answer, or even
>   multiple answers on the same question that is then visited by enough
>   unique IP Addresses you could receive badges for any of those shared
>   links, so you technically could be awarded multiple badges for the
>   same question.
>
> The badge descriptions have been updated to say
>
> > Share a link to a post...
>
> We are also in the process of awarding the badges with the new
>   queries, so you might get some notifications in your inbox.
>
> With the change in the logic it does mean that some users were awarded
>   badges that would no longer qualify - since we're no longer
>   aggregating up to the question. These numbers were very small, so we
>   are not going to be revoking any badges due to the change in logic.
>
> We also identified a small number of users who will receive duplicate
>   badges on the initial rollout of the new logic - meaning they were
>   awarded for a question with the old logic, but now are being awarded
>   for an answer - the duplicate badges will be removed over the next few
>   days after the corrected badges are awarded.

Comment: This is why I love meta. Anywhere else, I would have filed a support ticket thinking something was wrong, waited forever for a meh response. Here I found the answer in 5 seconds. Kudos.

Comment: Yes, the genius of Meta is that you can get that "meh" response in under 5 seconds. It is truly a magical platform! @bishop

Comment: That's the magic of meh-ta.

Comment: Is there a way to find out where the link I shared is located? It shows the destination, although not the origin.

Comment: @l'L'l try your memory. It is a link you posted somewhere, as it has to include your userID to make it count.

Comment: @l'L'l Most of my new badges where from links in comments on other Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange posts. You can find those in the "Linked" section in the right sidebar.

Comment: @l'L'l You can search for comments containing the URL using this data explorer query: [Search posts by UserId, comment text](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/151786/search-posts-by-userid-comment-text)

Comment: Thanks for the post.  My badges went down from .3 .11 to .1 .1.  I think there is still a badge bug out there.  My claim can be confirmed in my account, bottom part where it states 381 .3 .11 but shows different on my reputation header section.

Comment: @mugé Those are your badges on Meta. They're different from regular SO. Here on Meta you only have "Yearling" and "Supporter". If you go to your profile on stackoverflow.com (instead of meta.stackoverflow.com) you'll see "•2 •11".

Comment: I was awarded several "announcer" badges earlier today, but they were removed. An hour ago I had in total 213 bronze badges but now they are down to just 184. What is happening? Has the logic changed again?

Comment: @mzjn As mentioned in the last paragraph `We also identified a small number of users who will receive duplicate badges on the initial rollout of the new logic - meaning they were awarded for a question with the old logic, but now are being awarded for an answer - the duplicate badges will be removed over the next few days after the corrected badges are awarded.` This was done this morning.

Comment: @l'L'l As I understand it, that would be impossible in general as these links could be shared off of the SE network and/or in multiple places.

Comment: nice timing, as i now have a hat

Comment: a question: two days ago I had Announcer badge ("B1"). yesterday I got another ("B2"). today I lost "B1". Is it another update, or a bug?

Comment: @ASh see the last paragraph in the answer

Comment: @Taryn, I suppose it can be possible explanation. I didn't check which post it was for B1. Thanks

Comment: When can we be sure that all correction have been done? And will there be a feature to trade 100 (or so) bronze badges for a silver badge?

Comment: What if someone else has shared a link to my question/answer aka post, how do I find out where was it shared?

Comment: @John You can't, even Stack doesn't have that info. That's why the badge doesn't track links _shared_, it tracks incoming visits **from** an offsite page where a link was shared. Until an incoming session loads that content with a referer set, there's no way to know the links are out there. (Short of crawling the entire web looking for them, anyway.) — Now, if you want to know what offsite link(s) has/have brought people to your post... well, TBH I have no idea if you can do that. Probably not? The badge stats are based on visitor IPs, so exposing the underlying data has privacy implications.

Comment: @FeRD I don't think it's limited to offsite referrals. Most of the answers I have shared (and received badges for) have been on comments or even in other answers. It's not impossible for SE to track the referral sources either. Most browsers include the referer (sic) as a header. This doesn't include any private information. But of course if they have not been tracking this data already, they won't be able to add it in later except for links that continue to receive clicks

Comment: @andrewtweber Oh, no, of course they can (and do) track the referral sources. My point was simply, _until_ an incoming session points back to that link via a referrer header, there's no way to know the link is out there*. John had asked "how do I find out where [a Q or A] was shared?" (* For offsite links, anyway. Good point about on-site links, I hadn't realized those counted as well.)