# Potential Bug - Badges not awarded in full?

Tags: support, badges, achievements-dialog

On the main Stack Overflow site, up until about a week ago I had 68 bronze badges. Then one day in my feed I received notifications that I'd been awarded 8 bronze Announcer badges for links shared in different questions. I now have 69 bronze badges??

The number momentarily during that day went up to 76, but soon after reverted to 69. Have other people experienced similar (i.e. is it a bug?) or what is the explanation for this? I've seen it re-iterated many times in Meta Stack Overflow that once a badge is earned, it is never lost. This doesn't seem to be the case!

Comment: Also , I had earned this badge before, earlier in the year, and now when I click into my badges, it only shows 8 announcer badges, all awarded on Dec 12.

Comment: If anything, it is no longer in the database, at least not was published this morning: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1170930. I'm not sure if a mod has access to achievement history of a user. Probably needs a dev and lots of digging.

Comment: Well the count add up, you currently have 69 bronze badges. Either the Announcer badges were awarded multiple times by mistakes and then later corrected, or other badges were removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why was I just awarded a bunch of "Announcer" badges?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392137/why-was-i-just-awarded-a-bunch-of-announcer-badges) — Pay special attention to the last paragraph of the top answer.

Comment: In short, new announcer badges were awarded and then the duplicate ones were removed.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, that answers the question, although perhaps in future, decisions as such that will affect users' badges should be added to blog, or users should be notified to their inbox?

Comment: I think this affected way more users than they anticipated. The question I linked has been featured on meta since the day the badge logic was changed. You should be able to find it in the yellow box on the right side of this page (or on the bottom for small screens).

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, I've seen it there since I asked my question.