# Why can't I see the review queue in the post timeline after an edit?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, review-queues, reopen-closed

I have edited and voted to reopen the following question: [How do browsers calculate width when child depends on parent, and parent's depends on child's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63001886/8620333) but after more than 10 days I see nothing [in the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63001886/timeline?filter=NoVoteDetail) about a *review*

Is the question still pending inside the review queue or it never went there? I don't know how to verify this. I already reviewed all the CSS questions in the queue but I suppose I cannot see the ones where I voted to reopen.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/26737150) it is. Still pending.

Comment: @Ivar: Out of curiosity, how did you find that review?

Comment: @BDL In the reopen queue filtered on the [width] tag. Came up as the first review.

Comment: Mods can see pending reviews, it's there in the timeline. One more reason to be a mod :)

Comment: @SamuelLiew yes ... but if I am a Mod I can reopen all the question with a single vote ;) .. by the way, is there any *expiration* inside the queue? If no one review the question after a certain time, will it be removed from the queue?

Comment: @SamuelLiew Apologies for off-topicking this strand, but you have locked [the relevant post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387546). Tim Post [has](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396255#comment773616_396255) (twice) [promised](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396255#comment784466_396255) an update. What good is re-featuring that other post? Does it need new answers? I can't downvote it a second time. I was going to post a Meta question (and request featuring) asking Tim for a response, but not after just two weeks.

Comment: @Michael I didn't see the update from Tim earlier. Thanks!

Comment: @TemaniAfif Reopen votes expire in the same time-frames as close-votes, so 4 or 14 days after the most recent vote, depending on the number of views the question has (>=100 views is 4 days). As far as I know, questions are removed from the reopen queue under the similar criteria as for the CV queue (just substitute reopen for close).

Comment: @Makyen thanks for the info. Is this the "invalidated" message that appear in the timeline after the vote expire or I will see nothing in the timeline?

Comment: @TemaniAfif A review task shows as "invalidated" for basically any reason that the post was removed from a review queue, other than actually completing the review and having an actionable result, this includes things like the flag or vote which put it in the review queue aging away.

Comment: @Makyen I am going to bother your a little .. If I take this example of question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63401655/8620333 ... my reopen vote expires and the question wasn't reopened and I see nothing in the timeline about the *aging away*. Why is that?