# Do status-* tags block featured posts from getting to community bulletin at sidebar?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, meta, community-bulletin

As explained in details of particular recent change [any status- tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400216/839601) now blocks a question from getting to [hot-meta-posts](/questions/tagged/hot-meta-posts) (in the past, only status-completed tag had this effect).

Referred explanation does not state that status- tag make similar effect of blocking featured posts from getting to community bulletin at sidebar. However, [per this experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400218/839601) it looks like happening (thanks to moderator who helped in testing this).

We accounted for possibility of 6-hour caching (in fact we waited for over 15 hours after a post was tagged featured), we even removed featured tag from some other post to make sure that there are enough slots at sidebar but still, featured post having also tag status-completed tag was not observed in sidebar.

---

I would like to understand whether it is really so that status-* tags block featured post from getting to sidebar (or maybe I missed something in above experiment).

If block is for real then I would also like to understand if this is intentional or some oversight (bug)?

Finally, in case if this block is intentional then I would like to learn about the reasoning to have it.

Comment: ...additional question, not directly related to SO is, whether this is network wide?

Comment: Featured posts are not HMPs. Status tags have no impact on them

Comment: I think the cache is stuck.

Comment: @Catija I considered this possibility but decided to ask anyway after seeing how unfeatured question was dropped off the sidebar (in less than an hour). I know that caches can stuck in weirdest ways but seeing it apparently updated made me feel it is worth asking

Comment: Yeah... let me see if I can get someone to poke it... You can see the Election announcement is locked and still shows up in [meta-tag:featured] - It's not showing up in the bulletin but it's still stuck as a featured post. related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297870/post-remains-featured-in-the-bulletin-even-if-featured-tag-is-removed

Comment: Yes, featured posts are being filtered by status tags. This is not intentional. Fix is on the way.

Comment: I think it would be good to distinguish between the various parts of the "sidebar" in questions like these, considering how much goes into it. For instance, HNQ, Linked, Related, HMP, Featured on MSO, Featured on MSE, The Overflow Blog, Stack Overflow Blog... All of these show up on the "sidebar" (see [tag info page for `sidebar`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/sidebar/info)).

Comment: @HereticMonkey my mistake, sorry - I edited to use more specific tag community-bulletin

Comment: @Catija kick it. It worked before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Status tags no longer block featured posts from appearing in the community bulletin.

---

> status- this or that
> tag blocking disabled now
> featured posts run free