# How many questions should be on the hot meta questions?

Tags: support, community-bulletin

I've seen them all. From 4 non-featured meta questions to just 1. There seems to have been some changes in how many there should be that there isn't a canonical that explains the behavior for Stack Overflow. Right now, there is [1 hot meta post, 1 featured on Meta SO, 1 featured on Meta Stack Exchange, and 2 blog posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJb03.png), which should have two extra slot if [the rules on this post are to be believed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/213575) (which says that MSE posts don't count agains the 4 slots). But I've seen as many as 3 hot meta post, with 1 featured on MSE, 1 featured in MSO and two blog posts. Is there any [need to kick it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400257/do-status-tags-block-featured-posts-from-getting-to-community-bulletin-at-side#comment789311_400257)?

Comment: I think I had seen 5(bug?) HMP shortly after the return of HMP on SO...

Comment: And yet another day passes with me still wondering why they even removed that in the first place...

Comment: I saw 5 at one point. Perhaps give it a kick?